# How to anonymise user names and emails?

Tags: 7, users, drush, staging

The developer stages need their user names and email address anonymised. I did not find anything googling the subject matter. Maybe somebody developed a Drush extension for this? Any other suggestions are welcome too.

Comment: I've found module to anonymize user comment [comment anonymizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/anon_comment)

Comment: @АртемИльин the module is not related. The idea is to protect the identity of site users when developers work on their experimental or developer instance of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `drush sql-sync` command to sync the database and obscure email addresses and the user passwords during db deployment.

> `--sanitize` Obscure email addresses and reset passwords in the user table post-sync.

Check `drush help sql-sync` for help.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know! However in my case the sync is produced from a daily backup using mysqldump, but I might change that system to use drush instead. Below what I did using some SQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this:

```
drush sql-query "
  UPDATE users 
  SET 
    name=CONCAT('User-',uid),
    mail=CONCAT(uid,'@anon.com'), 
    init=CONCAT(uid,'old@anon.com') 
  WHERE uid > 0;"
drush upwd User-1 --password=SecureAdminPassword
```

Answer (score 2):

You need, `drush sql-sanitize`

```
$ drush sql-sanitize -h
Run sanitization operations on the current database. You can add more sanitization to this command by implementing hook_drush_sql_sync_sanitize().

Examples:
 drush sql-sanitize                        Sanitize database without modifying any passwords.
 --sanitize-password=no
 drush sql-sanitize                        Sanitizes database but exempts two user fields from modification.
 --whitelist-fields=field_biography,field
 _phone_number

Options:
 --db-prefix                               Enable replacement of braces in sanitize queries.
 --db-url                                  A Drupal 6 style database URL. E.g., mysql://root:pass@127.0.0.1/db
 --sanitize-email                          The pattern for test email addresses in the sanitization operation, or "no" to keep email addresses unchanged. May contain replacement patterns %uid, %mail or %name. Example value: user+%uid@localhost
 --sanitize-password                       The password to assign to all accounts in the sanitization operation, or "no" to keep passwords unchanged. Example value: password
 --whitelist-fields                        A comma delimited list of fields exempt from sanitization.

Aliases: sqlsan
```

Comment: I would need to write hook_drush_sql_sync_sanitize() to also sanitize the user names.